# All templates automatically private

Tags: routing, templating

Is there a way to make all templates automatically private? Or do I really have to put an _ before every single one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your templates will be private if they are contained in a folder prefixed with a "_"... So just make a folder like that, and put everything else inside of it:

```
/craft/templates/_everything/myprivatefile.html
```

Comment: Ahh nice, didn't know this also works for folders :) Thank you!